# Elegant, functional way to extract data from this nested R list

Tags: r, functional-programming, config, tidyverse

Given the following configuration object:

```
sourceClust = list(
  clust1 = list(
    prop = 0.25,
    Dim1 = list(
      mean = 2,
      sd   = 0.05
    ) ,
    Dim2 = list(
     mean = 3,
     sd = .1
    )
  ),
  clust2 = list(
    Dim1 = list(
      mean = 4,
      sd   = .1
    ),
    Dim2 = list(
      mean = 3,
      sd = 0.2
    ),
    prop = 0.75
  )
);
```

Is there an elegant, functional way to extract the data in the following format?

```
clusterMeans = data.frame(Dim1=c(2,4),Dim2=c(3,3));
clusterSD = data.frame(Dim1 = c(0.05,0.1), Dim2 = c(0.1,0.2));
clusterProp = c(0.25, 0.75);
```

I understand that the above can be accomplished with some nested loops, but I'm trying to see if I can use functional styling to accomplish this task. I'm looking for a solution in base R or using a library (tidyverse is great).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```r
order_df <- function(x) unlist(x)[order(names(unlist(x)))]
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(sourceClust, order_df)))
df
#>        Dim1.mean Dim1.sd Dim2.mean Dim2.sd prop
#> clust1         2    0.05         3     0.1 0.25
#> clust2         4    0.10         3     0.2 0.75
```

then just subset the columns out:

```r
clusterMeans <- df[grepl("mean", names(df))]
clusterSD    <- df[grepl("sd", names(df))]
clusterProp  <- df[[grep("prop", names(df))[1]]]
```

---

Or in pipe form, producing a named list of data frames:

```
sourceClust %>% 
  lapply(function(x) unlist(x)[order(names(unlist(x)))]) %>%
  {do.call(rbind, .)} %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  {lapply(c("mean", "sd", "prop"), function(x) .[grep(x, names(.))])} %>%
  `names<-`(c("mean", "sd", "prop"))
># $mean
>#        Dim1.mean Dim2.mean
># clust1         2         3
># clust2         4         3
># 
># $sd
>#        Dim1.sd Dim2.sd
># clust1    0.05     0.1
># clust2    0.10     0.2
># 
># $prop
>#        prop
># clust1 0.25
># clust2 0.75
```

Comment: Wow, this is a really interesting solution.  I was skeptical at first but I see that once your solution is applied i can use the dplyr library to dynamically pull the columns by name and order by dimension at the end(in case I have multiple dimensions).  I'm going to keep this idea in mind for the future.  unlisting, do.call(rbind) into a df, then use regexp to select the columns.

Comment: @Battlefrisk yes, you don't even need dplyr. Example updated.

Comment: Sorry to ask for so much, but could you suggest a good way to rewrite this using pipes?

Comment: @Battlefrisk I think it's less elegant, but I've added a piped version

Comment: You’re right it is. But this was really helpful to see something complex done in two ways. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The `purrr` package has some helper functions like `map` and `pluck` which can help. For example

```
clusterProp <- map_dbl(sourceClust, "prop")
```

and

```
map_dbl(sourceClust, ~pluck(., "Dim1", "sd"))
```

You can also do

```
cols <- c("Dim1", "Dim2")
clusterMeans <- map(cols, function(col) map_dbl(sourceClust, ~pluck(., col, "mean"))) %>%
  set_names(cols) %>% as_tibble()
clusterSD  <- map(cols, function(col) map_dbl(sourceClust, ~pluck(., col, "sd"))) %>%
  set_names(cols) %>% as_tibble()
```

But since you are doing so much reshaping, it's not exactly "elegant".

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't realize map could be used as a getter like that.  I assumed it required a function to be passed to reduce each row to a value.  I think the hard part here is the double nested means and sd.  I'm looking for a solution that works independent of how many Dims there are, so i probably need some RegExp.

Comment: If you have `prop=` at the same level as `Dim*=` it's going to be very hard to treat them differently without knowing the specific names you want to operate on.